# How to write a business logic and save in the database or return to the user

Tags: grails

I have 2 questions.

1.) I need to save values to the database **AFTER** making some changes to it. For example if an user parameter says Date of birth = 1990-09-14 then i want to calculate the age of the person and save it in the database. How can i do it. The code is shown below.

2.) Can someone explain me the following code:

```
def save() {
    def appointmentInstance = new Appointment(params)
    if (!appointmentInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [appointmentInstance: appointmentInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'appointment.label', default: 'Appointment'), appointmentInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: appointmentInstance.id)
}
```

This is what i understand:

1. `def appointmentInstance = new Appointment(params)` - It takes all the parameters and save it to an instance called `appointmentInstance`
2. ```
   if (!appointmentInstance.save(flush: true)) {
               render(view: "create", model: [appointmentInstance: appointmentInstance])
               return
           }
   ```

What hapence here

3.) May i also know what happence in this example:

```
    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'appointment.label', default: 'Appointment'), appointmentInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: appointmentInstance.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the data into database after doing some change, you can do the following:

```
def save() {
     // calculate the age 
      def age = // your calculation

 // now you can save changes to db in 2 ways  

 // 1st way
 params.age = age
 def appointmentInstance = new Appointment(params)
 if (!appointmentInstance.save(flush: true)) {
    render(view: "create", model: [appointmentInstance: appointmentInstance])
    return
 }
// 2nd way

def appointmentInstance = new Appointment(params)
appointmentInstance.age = age
if (!appointmentInstance.save(flush: true)) {
    render(view: "create", model: [appointmentInstance: appointmentInstance])
    return
}

flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'appointment.label', default: 'Appointment'), appointmentInstance.id])
redirect(action: "show", id: appointmentInstance.id)
```

}

```
def appointmentInstance = new Appointment(params)
```

- It takes all the parameters and save it to an instance called appointmentInstance

```
if (!appointmentInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "create", model: [appointmentInstance: appointmentInstance])
            return
        }
```

save() is a function of grails that retuns true or false. 
The save method informs the persistence context that an instance should be saved or updated. The object will not be persisted immediately unless the flush argument is used.
When set to **true** flushes the persistence context, persisting the object immediately and updating the version column for optimistic locking

the purpose of render is to apply an inbuilt or user-defined Groovy template against a model so that templates can be shared and reused

If you are using render and you don't want to execute your next lines of code, then return statement is used. But in case of redirect, next line of code is not executed, so return is not used there.

```
flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'appointment.label', default: 'Appointment'), appointmentInstance.id])
```

Flash is a temporary storage map that stores objects within the session for the next request and the next request only, automatically clearing out the objects held there after the next request completes.
Generally used to show messages on gsp.

```
message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'appointment.label', default: 'Appointment'), appointmentInstance.id])
```

This code uses the **messages.properties** file located in i18n folder, All the default messages of grails are stored here. You can also add your custom messages here and provide a dynamic value to your message.

```
redirect(action: "show", id: appointmentInstance.id)
```

To redirect flow from one action to the next using an HTTP redirect. You can send id as a parameter in your url.